# How do I add a custom screen for a custom post type to be called from custom post row action?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, actions

I have custom post type called messages where I will store emails and my request is very specific. New post cannot be created and user cannot do anything with it except delete it. I have already added a custom post row action for viewing messages, but I want to view them in a custom screen where only the ID of the post will be passed in request.

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', function ($actions, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type === 'message') {
        unset($actions['edit']);
        unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
        $actions['view'] = '<a href="'.admin_url().'edit.php?post='.$post->ID.'&action=view_message" rel="bookmark">View</a>';
    }
    return $actions;
}, 10, 2);
```

As u can see I want the `action=view_message` to be my trigger.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a snippet from another theme I developed:

```
/**
* Add sub menu page to the custom post type
*/
function add_submenu_page_to_post_type()
{
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=newsletter',
        __('Newsletter SendMail', 'simplebyte'),
        __('SendMail', 'simplebyte'),
        'manage_options',
        'sendmail',
        'newsletter_sendmail_options_display'
    );
}
/**
* Options page callback
*/
function newsletter_sendmail_options_display()
{
    echo 'something';
}
```

Here's the a custom screen accessible as a submenu page in the cpt. Instead I want a screen like that, not visible, and to be able to pass it the post ID.

Comment: You could make all of the messages private, give users the capabilities to read private messages and delete them, and that would automatically remove the edit screen entirely.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I wan't no access to editor, for anyone, just viewing. And since disabling or removing fields from an edit post page is actually hell and a lot of work I thought why not make a custom screen. Look at my update, I posted a snipped from another theme I developed, I want something similar.

Comment: Giving users only "read private" and "delete" capabilities will only allow them to view the front end and the post listing screen - they won't be able to access the editor.